# Odd table rows not highlighting

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a table that highlights all the odd rows.

To do this, I just check what the row number is and apply the `alt` class to said row.

I then highlight the row on hover using a simple `:hover` in the CSS file.

It highlights the non-`.alt` rows perfectly, but not the `alt` rows.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.datagrid tr:hover, .datagrid tr.alt:hover {
    background-color:#497A43;
    color:#D3F0D4;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the first selector not sufficient? Surely `tr.alt`s are `tr`s?

Comment: show us the rule for non-`.alt` rows, please, and post some more CSS you think is relevant.

Comment: is the color and background for the `.alt` rows the same as hover perhaps?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, I tried making it more specific out of hopes that it will work then, but also didn't.
@ EliranMalka - There's no rule. They are just plain white with table font color.
@ MoinZaman - No they are not.

Comment: @DarkRanger: Do you have !important in your `.alt` styles? It would help if you could replicate an isolated instance of this on http://jsbin.com

Comment: Then you must have some other style you've not shown us that is more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont apply those cumbersome class changing methods. Instead use the css selector

```
.datagrid tr:nth-child(even):hover {background: #CCC}
.datagrid tr:nth-child(odd):hover {background: #FFF}
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSc4F/)

Comment: this way the styling works even in the absence of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It works without needing the `.alt` selector.

See http://jsbin.com/ixokoj/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
.datagrid tr:hover, .datagrid tr.alt:hover 

{


    background-color:#497A43;


    color:#D3F0D4;


}
```

use the following

```
.datagrid tr.alt:hover 

{

    background-color:#497A43;

    color:#D3F0D4;


}
```

The above will apply the background color and color to the rows which has class as "alt" and only when they are hovered.

Hope this helped.